# How do I filter a glob in zsh

Tags: zsh, wildcards

Basically I can use a glob in zsh to a list.  Often, it turns out, I would like to filter that list, grep'ishly I'm wondering though, if I need to do that.

Does zsh have a method to filter a list?  I fear this is an obvious question, but it's a low yield day today, mentally.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is kind of a weird question, seeing as zsh is the only shell with this feature. It's called [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers). The manual is, as usual, rather terse and devoid of examples. The [Zsh-lovers](http://grml.org/zsh/zsh-lovers.html) page has a few examples. [Googling `zsh "glob qualifiers"`](http://www.google.com/search?q=zsh+%22glob+qualifiers%22) turns up a few blog posts and tutorials. You can also search for [`"glob qualifier"` on this site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22glob%20qualifier%22).

The basics: glob qualifiers are in parentheses at the end of the glob. The most useful ones are the punctuation signs to select only certain file types.

```
echo *(/)      # directories
echo *(.)      # regular files
echo *(@)      # symbolic links
echo *(-/)     # directories and symbolic links to directories
```

There are other qualifiers to filter on metadata such as size, date and ownership.

```
# files owned by the user running zsh, over 1MB, last modified more than 7 days ago
echo *(ULm+1m+7)
```

Glob qualifiers can also control the order of matches, and restrict the number of matches.

```
echo *(Om[1,10])     # The 10 oldest files
```

You can set up arbitrary filters by calling a function, with the `+` qualifier (you can even put the code inline with the `e` qualifier, if you don't mind the tricky quoting).

Note that unfortunately all of this only works on globs. If you want to build a list of file names this way, you need to filter when you're globbing. If you want to filter a list that you've already built, there's a completely different syntax, [parameter expansion flags](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags), which can only perform simple text filtering (`"${(@)ARRAY:#PATTERN}"`).

Comment: Also, with the [`EXTENDED_GLOB`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#Expansion-and-Globbing) option, you can use the `^x` and `x~y` [glob operators](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Operators) for pathname-based exclusions while globbing (à la `grep -v`).

Comment: Parameter expansion was the thing. Thanks for the utterly complete answer. Appreciated.

Comment: Ok, I now love zsh