# Is it possible to reference the most recently modified file in a command line argument?

Tags: bash, command-line, files, wildcards, date

I frequently download PDF files with heinous numeric file names from my browser.  These automatically go into `~/Downloads`.  Ideally I would like to just be able to open these files with:

```
evince "the most recently modified file"
```

without having to open `~/Downloads` to find the file name.

Is there a simple way to specify "the most recently modified file" in `bash`?

NOTE: I know that it is *possible* to do this, but ideally I am looking for a solution that would be simpler than `ls -t`'ing `~/Downloads` to check the name.

Comment: There is no way to do this with `bash` that is both simple and foolproof.  I believe `zsh` can do this with the `*(om[1])` glob.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
evince "$(ls -t | head -n1)"
```

While it will handle spaces, tabs, and (I believe) printing specials, it will break if the filename contains a newline, and possibly on some other non-printing characters.

Comment: This [won't work](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) for a lot of different files.

Comment: @l0b0 I am aware of the limitations of parsing ls, that's why I mentioned them.

Comment: thanks, this is simple and will definitely work for my purposes (who the heck puts newlines in a filename!?)

Comment: @DQdlM: Hackers and people who test their code properly.

Comment: This is good enough for most simple cases.

Answer (score 5):

This is a more correct and robust approach than `ls -t`, at the cost of some additional complexity.

## Setup

Add a short shell script (code below) to your `$PATH`.  `~/bin` is a good place for it.

Remember to make sure

- the script is executable `chmod +x ~/bin/script_name`
- `~/bin` is in your `$PATH`

## Usage

Pass the command you want to run on the newest file in `~/Download` to `last_download`.

### Examples

Assuming you named the script `last_download`

- `last_download` (no arguments): runs `evince`, the default command, on the newest file in `~/Downloads`
- `last_download mplayer`: runs `mplayer` on the newest file in `~/Downloads`
- `last_download cp -t ~/Desktop`: copies the newest file in `~/Downloads` to `~/Desktop`

## Code

```
#!/bin/sh
# Usage: last_download [cmd [options]...]

newest=
dir=~/Downloads

# default command
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
        set -- evince;
fi

# find newest file
for f in "$dir"/*; do
        if [ -z "$newest" ] || [ "$f" -nt "$newest" ]; then
                newest="$f"
        fi
done
if ! [ -e "$newest" ]; then
        exit 1
fi

# run command on newest file
"$@" "$newest"
```

---

<sup>Note: The script only looks in `~/Download` but it would not be hard to generalize it to support any directory, in which case a name change would also be warranted.</sup>

Comment: Well done, nice and thorough.

Comment: ... except it puts the command to run outside your shell context, so it won't work with bash builtin commands, aliases, functions, anything set up in your bashrc, etc.

Comment: @user112553 Yes that is a good point.  However, it would be trivial to convert the script into a function if the user so desired.

Comment: True. I just saw everyone else nitpicking and wanted my own nit. ;)

Comment: @jw013 Sorry to ask (I'm a novice) but, how would you convert the script into a function so that it will recognize your aliases, etc? I tried:
function last_file {
    source ~/scripts/last_file.sh
}


At the end of my .bashrc, but aliases were not preserved.

Comment: @user1247 I would just copy paste it instead of sourcing it, since you have to tweak it anyways.  `last_file () { #copy paste code here }`.  The only change to make is to change the `exit` to `return`, so the function doesn't exit your shell.

Comment: @jw013 Hmm, still the exact same behavior; it works but doesn't recognize aliases (I did source my .bashrc don't worry). ETA: I made a test script: alias echohello="echo hello";
function test() {
    echohello
}, which works fine. So it has something to do with how your script handles input

Comment: @user1247 Sorry I got distracted from the bigger picture.  The fundamental problem is aliases are expanded when functions are read, *not* when they are executed.  The function expands its arguments to obtain the command to run, so passing in aliases won't work.  The solution is simple: change your aliases to functions, which do work, since functions supersede aliases anyways.

Comment: @jw013 Thanks, I read somewhere else that that is a good idea, so I'll do it, even though I have a **lot** of aliases :)

Comment: @jw013 Actually, it still doesn't work correctly. If I give the last_file () function a function as a command, it doesn't run it. The function exits fine, and correctly finds the most recent file, but it does not run the command I give it. I can't figure out what is going wrong :( ... you might want to just try it out yourself, as the copy-paste job will only take a sec.

Comment: @user1247 type `set -x` (turn on xtrace) and try again and see what it tells you.

Comment: @jw013 OK, this tells me that some of the aliases I have turned into functions are not taking arguments! For example: function cdtest () {
    cd
}
When I run "cdtest Downloads/" on the command line xtrace shows that only the command "cd" is run. On the other hand another function: function e() {
    emacs
}
Does work on when given arguments on the command line!!?? Is the difference that 'cd' is a bash builtin? But in either case xtrace shows the last_file () given the command 'e' or 'cdtest' runs only 'emacs' or 'cd' without the argument given to it.

Comment: @user1247 You have to make all your functions look like, e.g. `cdtest () { cd "$@"; }`, and then they should work with arguments.

Comment: thanks for this answer, it is probably more than I need but there is a lot to learn here!

Comment: 1) If something happens in a subfolder, this subfolder may be newer than the last real file. So I enclosed the inner `if` by `if [ -f "$f" ]; then ... fi`
2) It should probably be put into `~/.local/bin`
3) To make it applicable to the current folder replace `dir=~/Downloads` by `dir=\`pwd\` ` 4) It is very comfortable to replace the default action by `ls` to quickly check which file will get the command

Answer (score 4):

```
exec zsh
evince ~/Downloads/*.pdf(om[1])
```

or if you don't want to switch to zsh

```
cd ~/Downloads
zsh -c 'evince ./*.pdf(om[1])'
```

The bits between parentheses are [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers). `om` changes the order on globs to use the modification time rather than the name (newest first). `[1]` means to use only the first match.

For more information, see [this answer to "How do I filter a glob in zsh"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31504/how-do-i-filter-a-glob-in-zsh/31505#31505).

Answer (score 3):

You can use a modified [find_date_sorted](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/22227cfc6a604c837baceb65f5e92216b2669856/.bash_aliases#L38):

```
last_download() {
    while IFS= read -r -d '' -u 9
    do
        cut -d ' ' -f 3- <<< "$REPLY"
        break
    done 9< <(find ~/Downloads -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td %TH:%TM:%TS %p\0' | sort -rz)
}
```

It'll work with any filenames. To open the file:

```
evince "$(last_download)"
```

Comment: Actually this doesn't work for files with a newline in their name.

Comment: @Kevin: Ah yes, because of `head`. My bad. Should be fixed now.

Comment: Even though file names ending in newlines are uncommon, it should be noted that command substitution strips *trailing* newlines, even when quoted.

Comment: D'oh! You're right, of course. You'd have to use a [trick](https://gist.github.com/716763) to fix that.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I always learn way more than I intend when I come on SE!

Answer (score 0):

No, and even if there were, you couldn't be sure some system log won't usually be the most recently updated file.

Kevin's answer (he beat me to it) works if you just want to avoid *manually* opening `~/Downloads`.