# remove oldest files

Tags: shell, files, rm

I`m trying to delete old files from directory and leave only 3 newest files.

```
cd /home/user1/test

while [ `ls -lAR | grep ^- | wc -l` < 3 ] ; do

    rm `ls -t1 /home/user/test | tail -1`
    echo " - - - "

done
```

something is wrong with conditional statement.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to loop over files, [never use `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)*. tl;dr There are lots of situations where you'd end up deleting the wrong file, or even all files.

That said, unfortunately this is a tricky thing to do right in Bash. There's a working answer over at <strike>a [duplicate question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29205/3645)</strike> [my even older `find_date_sorted`](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/9a4fe17bc77de1b16e9e03fcc87056b28be3cd15/.bash_aliases#L43) which you can use with small modifications:

```
counter=0
while IFS= read -r -d '' -u 9
do
    let ++counter
    if [[ counter -gt 3 ]]
    then
        path="${REPLY#* }" # Remove the modification time
        echo -e "$path" # Test
        # rm -v -- "$path" # Uncomment when you're sure it works
    fi
done 9< <(find . -mindepth 1 -type f -printf '%TY-%Tm-%TdT%TH:%TM:%TS %p\0' | sort -rz) # Find and sort by date, newest first
```

* No offense guys - I also used `ls` before. But it really isn't safe.

Edit: [New `find_date_sorted`](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/commit/f4263a7e0e5c436029d5d4e6b3740b28addf6dae) with unit tests.

Comment: I second the part about not parsing ls. Also the script is neat but I think it could be done in a one liner, let me check ...

Comment: Well, you can always compact Bash code into a one-liner, but the issue is whether it'll be readable :)

Comment: If I may mercilessly steal an idea from @Peter.O, try `((++counter>3))` as your test. It's nicely succinct. As for oneliners: If brevity is a concern wrap the code in a function, then don't worry about it.

Comment: @Sorpigal Neat shortcut

Answer (score 5):

By far the easiest method is to use zsh and its [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers): `Om` to sort by decreasing age (i.e. oldest first) and `[1,3]` to retain only the first three matches.

```
rm ./*(Om[1,3])
```

See also [How do I filter a glob in zsh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31504/how-do-i-filter-a-glob-in-zsh) for more examples.

And do heed [l0b0's advice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35792/bash-remove-oldest-files/35797#35797): your code will break horribly if you have file names that contain shell special characters.

Comment: Woa woa hold the train, is this really a complete solution in 1 line?

Comment: @Ryan That's zsh for you.

Answer (score 5):

To delete all but the 3 newest files using a zsh glob, you can use `Om` (capital O) to sort the files from oldest to newest and a subscript to grab the files you want.

```
rm ./*(Om[1,-4])
#    | ||||  ` stop at the 4th to the last file (leaving out the 3 newest)
#    | |||` start with first file (oldest in this case)
#    | ||` subscript to pick one or a range of files
#    | |` look at modified time
#    | ` sort in descending order
#    ` start by looking at all files
```

Other examples:

```
# delete oldest file (both do the same thing)
rm ./*(Om[1])
rm ./*(om[-1])

# delete oldest two files
rm ./*(Om[1,2])

# delete everything but the oldest file
rm ./*(om[1,-2])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following function to get the newest file in a directory:

```
newest_in() 
{ 
    local newest=$1

    for f;do [[ $f -nt $newest ]] && newest="$f"; done;

    printf '%s\n' "$newest"
}
```

Give it a different set of files by exculding the newest file after each iteration.

**Tip:** If you hold the initial set of files in an array called "${files[@]}", then save the index of the newest file found, and `unset 'files[index]'` before the next iteration.

**Usage:** `newest_in [set of files/directories]`

**Sample output:**

```
[rany$] newest_in ./*
foo.txt
[rany$]
```

Answer (score -1):

First, the `-R` option is for recursion, which is probably not what you want - that will search in all subdirectories as well.  Second, the `<` operator (when not being seen as redirection) is for string comparison.  You probably want `-lt`. Try:

```
while [ `ls -1A | grep ^- | wc -l` -lt 3 ]
```

But I would use find here:

```
while [ `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print | wc -l` -lt 3 ]
```

Comment: Both will fail if one or more of the file names contain a '$\n'.

Answer (score -1):

I know it's [a sin](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) to parse `ls`, but what about this:

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 | xargs ls -ltr | sed '1,3d' | awk '{print $9}' | xargs rm
```

A quick test with 5 empty files:

```
$ >1
$ >2
$ >3
$ >4
$ >5
$ find . -type f -maxdepth 1 | xargs ls -lt | sed '1,3d' | awk '{print $9}' | xargs rm
$ ls -1
3
4
5
```

Comment: This one will fail for two reasons - Parsing ``ls`` output and using ``find`` and ``xargs`` together in the wrong way. If you combine ``find`` and ``xargs`` I recommend you to use ``find``s ``-print0`` and accordingly ``xargs``s ``-O`` options. Read about [Using Find](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind) for more information about the subject. You might also want to take a look and read about why [Parsing ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) is very bad.

Answer (score -2):

This one-liner does it all I think:

```
ls -t1 /home/user/test | tail -n +4 | xargs -I{} rm -- "{}"
```

Comment: ls is a tool for interactively looking at file information. Its output is formatted for humans and will cause bugs in scripts. Use globs or find instead. Understand why: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score -2):

Here's one solution:

```
rm /appserver/webapplogs/$(ls -t1 /appserver/webapplogs/|tail -1)
```

Comment: @bakbak ls is a tool for interactively looking at file information. Its output is formatted for humans and will cause bugs in scripts. [Look here to understand why](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Specificaly speaking about your answer - this one will break if one or more of the files contain a $'\n' character. Also, the [Command Substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution) ( i.e. $(...) ) lacks double-quotes which brings up another important subject - [Word Splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting)!