# Remove 50GB oldest files in busybox when used capacity reaches 95%

Tags: shell, files, find, cron, busybox

Ok I have requested a code here but initial I didn't ask to make it busybox compatible. My bad. I'm new to Linux and coding.

The code needs to do the following:

> Delete 50GB of oldest data (dir with files) from a directory when the HD reaches a capacity of
>   95%.

The code they gave me is, that is not working with busybox:

```
DIRS="a/ b/"
MAXDELBYTES="53687091200" # 50GB
DELBYTES="0"

find $DIRS -type f -printf "%T@ %s %p\n" | sort -r -n | while read time bytes filename
do
    rm -fv "$filename"
    DELBYTES=$((DELBYTES + bytes))

    if [ $DELBYTES -ge $MAXDELBYTES ]; then break; fi
done
```

What is not working:

- -printf (changed it to -print)
- %T@ %s %p\n (don't know what to change it to)
- Do not know what else isn't working. I'm new to coding and Linux.

Now this need to be translated to busybox so it will work on my embedded Linux system. Also a cron command needs to be added so it runs every Friday.

Comment: Is there another way to let this work in busybox, even when the filename has spaces?

Comment: You cannot simply change _printf_ to _print_ and expect the command to do the same afterwards. _printf_ is needed for sorting the output later. You seem to have a non-GNU version of find which has no -printf option, so it won't work that way on your system.

Comment: @warl0ck No, it won't. In the `read` command, everything after the `bytes` field will be assigned to the last variable: `filename`. The `rm` has quotes around `$filename`, so everything should work with spaces. It *would*, however, fail in case of filenames with linebreaks in names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the *busybox* implementation of *find* does not offer custom output formatting, you need to outsource the formatting task to a separate program :) Luckily, even `busybox` includes the handy **`stat`** command. It's output format fields differ from the ones that *GNU find* uses, so the symbols you need to use are different. The script below assumes that `find` and `stat` are those that come from `busybox`.

```
DIRS="a/ b/"
MAXDELBYTES="53687091200" # 50GB
DELBYTES="0"

find $DIRS -type f -exec stat -c "%Y %s %n" {} \; | sort -r -n | while read time bytes filename
do
    rm -fv "$filename"
    DELBYTES=$((DELBYTES + bytes))

    if [ $DELBYTES -ge $MAXDELBYTES ]; then break; fi
done
```

As always, read each command's description before you use it. In case of `busybox`, you won't find manpages for them, but you can use `--help` to display usage information.

Be warned, that this solution can break things in an unlikely situation, when file names contain newline symbols in them! This should not occur on a healthy system, but might happen, for instance, if someone manages to either break into the system or exploit some vulnerability that allows arbitrary file creation.

To prevent accidentally removing useful files in such cases, you should first find and remove all files that include newlines in their names. To list those, run:

```
find / -name "*
*"
```

(There is **only** a newline between the asterisks.) Then, when you're sure all those files are not needed, delete them using either

```
find / -name "*
*" -delete
```

or

```
find / -name "*
*" -print0 | xargs -0 rm -vf
```

Both should work with `busybox`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Does it also delete folders in that directory? or only files?

I get following error: `code`: find: stat: No such file or directory - so it means it halts with stat. Or does it mean my HD is not full for 95%

Comment: @Jasper That means your Busybox doesn't include the `stat` utility. Busybox is highly tunable, many features are optional.

Comment: Ah dammit! It is for the linux build "OpenElec." A lightweight XBMC version (media center). I guess the only solution is to ask if they can add support for `stat` in a future release?
Or can i add this myself?

Comment: WOW that was fast. They added it in the next release: https://github.com/OpenELEC/OpenELEC.tv/commit/9535082e262ae6ee6bcc5d731492d6ae46b5169f

Will report back to you when i tested this script in next beta  release from Openelec..

Answer (score 2):

Generally, [it's a bad idea to parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). But on an embedded system that has no `stat`, no zsh, no `find -printf`, no perl or other large scripting language, it's the only way of sorting files by date. Assuming that your file names contain no whitespace and none of `\'"` (which `xargs` mangles) — an assumption that your original script makes — you can use `xargs ls -str` to display files sorted by date, and display their size in the process.

```
find $DIRS -type f |
xargs ls -str |
while read kilobytes filename; do …
```

Note that the size is displayed in kilobytes instead of bytes. Furthermore, this is the on-disk space taken by the file rather than the number of bytes in the file. Usually, this number is the file size, rounded up to the next integer number of blocks, but it may be less if the file is [sparse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file). In a script that frees disk space, this is probably what you want.

There is a big caveat with the script above: it will only print its results in the right order if the number of files is small enough that `xargs` can make a single call to `ls`. If there are multiple calls to `ls`, each call will sort its arguments separately. You can print the file dates with `ls`, but sorting this human-readable output is very complicated. A better solution to at least detect the error case is to substitute the output of `find` into the command line.

```
{ set -f; IFS='
'; ls -str $(find $DIRS -type f); } |
while read -r kilobytes filename; do …
```