# Ignore case in Find command

Tags: linux, find, case-sensitivity

I want to search file in 2 different directories using find command,

```
find $file_dir1 $file_dir2  -name 'searchpattern*' | tail -10
```

I am using this command now, but it is case-sensitive search. 
I tried `-iname`, it is not supported in my linux box. I need to list all files ignoring case.

Comment: I assume this is a busybox-based system?

Comment: (though there's [evidence](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46016/117549) of busybox find supporting `-iname`)

Answer (score 5):

```
find "$file_dir1" "$file_dir2" \
  -name '[sS][eE][aA][rR][cC][hH][pP][aA][tT][tT][eE][rR][nN]*'
```

That is we replace letters like `x` with the `[xX]` bracket expression which matches on either `x` or `X`, effectively replacing a case sensitive match of lowercase `x` with a case insensitive match of `x`.

For some characters like `ﬃ` where the upper-case or lower-case translation isn't a single characters, you may need to resort to things like:

```
find "$file_dir1" "$file_dir2" \
  \( -name '*[sS][uU]ﬃ[xX]' -o -name '*[sS][uU]FFI[xX]' \)
```

as `[ﬃFFI]` would match on `ﬃ`, `F` or `I` instead of `ﬃ` or `FFI`.

If you can guarantee your file and directory names don't contain newline characters, you could also get `find` to print every file path, and use `awk` to filter on the file name:

```
find "$file_dir1" "$file_dir2" |
  awk -F/ 'tolower($NF) ~ /^searchpattern/'
```

(beware it's not necessarily equivalent to `toupper($NF) ~ /^SEARCHPATTERN/` like in the `ﬃ` case above or because not everybody (every locale) agrees on what the upper-case or lower-case variant of a letter is (for instance, is uppercase `i` `I` or `İ`?); you'll also find some variations in `grep -i` or other tool that do case insensive matching).

Comment: here 'searchpattern' is just parameter example. it is not the file name itself, it should be like[a-A,z-Z].

Comment: @ShreyasRK, whatever the pattern, you should be able to adapt using that technique. In any case, there's no saying what `[a-A,z-Z]` specifically would match, even in the C locale.

Comment: @ Stéphane Chazelas, here we dont know wthat the search pattern will be. And  will "find" search based on the first letter, or will it search from middle also.

Comment: @ShreyasRK, `[sS]` matches on either `s` or `S`, so `-name '[sS]*'` matches on files whose name starts with `s` or `S` followed by 0 or more characters (`*`).