# How I delete all files in a directory with specific extensions except the last 5 of them

Tags: shell-script, find, ls, xargs

The directory contains files with different extensions. I would like to delete all files with extensions .gz, zx, ext4 except the last 5 files. I can list all those files with

```
ls -l | grep '\.gz\|xz\|ext4$'
```

and I could just show the oldest 5 of them:

```
ls -l | grep '\.gz\|xz\|ext4$' | head -5
```

Or list the last 5 files:

```
ls -l | grep '\.gz\|xz\|ext4$' | tail -5
```

But I don't know how delete all of them except these 5 files that are listed in the above command.

Comment: What do you mean by "last 5 files"? What do you mean by "oldest"? `ls -l` doesn't sort files by modification time nor by creation time by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the usual sort order is ok (i.e. your files are named by the date), and your shell supports arrays, you can use them for this, avoiding [the usual caveats about using `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs):

```
F=(./*.{gz,xz,ext4})          # list files
G=("${F[@]:5}")               # pick all but the first five to another array
G=("${F[@]:0:${#F[@]}-5}")    # or pick all but the last five
rm -- "${G[@]}"               # remove them
```

`zsh` can sort by date in itself, so this would grab the matching files to an array, sorted by modification time

```
F=(./*.(gz|xz|ext4)(Om))
```

(`(Om)` for newest last, `(om)` for newest first.)
Process the array as above.

---

Of course, if you need to sort by modification date, can't use `zsh` and **know your filenames are nice**, a simple `ls -t | tail -n +6` would do.
<sub>(`tail -n +6` starts printing at the sixth line, i.e. skips the first five. I had an off-by-one at this at first.)</sub>

With GNU ls, I think we could do ask it to quote the filenames to create suitable input for the shell, and then fill the array with the output:

```
eval "F=($(ls -t --quoting-style=shell-always ./*.{xz,gz}))"
```

But that requires trusting that `ls` and the shell agree on how quotes are interpreted.

Comment: Even better with zsh (without the assign to array step): http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/160228/170373

Answer (score 1):

```
ls -1 | grep '\.gz$\|xz$\|ext4$' | tail -n +6 | xargs rm
```

Caveats:
    Your files should not have spaces/quotes.

```
set -f; set ./*.[gx]z ./*.ext4; [ "$#" -gt 5] && shift 5; rm -f "$@"
```

The below will work any sort of filenames:

```
td="`mktemp`" \
   find . -maxdepth 1 -type f \( -name \*.[gx]z -o -name \*.ext4 \) -exec sh -c '
      [ ! -s "$td" ] && [ "$#" -gt 5 ] && { shift 5; echo >> "$td"; }
      rm -f "$@"
   ' x {} +
rm "$td"
```

Answer (score 1):

You are nearly there.

Use the long option format to specify the number of lines required, and then negate it. (The opposite logic can be used with `tail`).

`head --lines=3` prints from head three lines

`head --lines=-3` prints from head except the last three

Here's an example using a `head` and an eight line file named `f`

```
$ cat f
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
line 6
line 7
line 8
$ head -3 f
line 1
line 2
line 3
$ head --lines=3 f
line 1
line 2
line 3
$ head --lines=-3 f
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
```

Check this part produces what you want before you start deleting files.

The long option isn't strictly required, but it doesn't have the legacy of having to be backward compatible with the evolution of the tail and head commands and I find it easier to remember.

`head -n-3` is equivalent with the long option `head --lines=-3 f`

See below

```
$ head -3 f #originally
line 1
line 2
line 3
$ head -n3 f #
line 1
line 2
line 3
$ head -n+3 f
line 1
line 2
line 3
$ head -n-3 f
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
$
```

Answer (score 1):

In bash:

`ls -1 *.{gz,xz,ext4} | head -n-5 | xargs -r rm`

The key insight is, that `head -n-5` will print all lines ENDING BEFORE the 5th from the end (i.e. all lines except the last 5). I believe you understand the rest.

The dual for `tail` would be `tail -n+6` which prints all lines STARTING FROM the 6th (i.e. all lines except the first 5).

Answer (score 0):

The following command will list all but the last 5 files:

```
ls -l | grep '\.gz\|xz\|ext4$' | head -n `expr \`ls | grep '\.gz\|xz\|ext4$' | wc -l\` - 4`
```

You should be able to convert it into command to delete files easily.