# Order of commands executed and redirection

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection

For a bash script I'm making, I need to delete all but the newest 2 files in a directory.

I decided to use `ls -tUr > somefile.txt` and then just tail the newest 2, move them somewhere else, `rm *`, and move them back.

For some reason, `somefile.txt` actually shows up (among the rest of the files) inside `somefile.txt` which screws up using the `tail` command.

So my question is, logically `ls` would return the current folder/files and then be redirected into `somefile.txt`, but clearly this isn't happening since `somefile.txt` must exist before `ls` runs; why is this?

Comment: Note for those that may be surprised to see a `-U` where that option means _unsorted_ in GNU `ls`, the OP is probably using a BSD system where `-U` means to use the creation time instead of last modification time.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using OS X for this particular script.

Comment: Has `--libxo` made it to macOS?

Comment: See [Warning regarding ‘>’](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/186126/70524) in the answers of the above question.

Comment: Also duplicate but from another site: https://askubuntu.com/q/728382/295286  Basically the answer is that redirections are always done first.

Comment: That's very nice, but what I'm working on isn't for Ubuntu, it is a generalized question about Linux Operating Systems concerning redirection, so actually, if you want to remove one, then remove that person's because they clearly posted it on the wrong site.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This answers the question "why does this happen?"

Yes, `somefile.txt` will actually be created before `ls` is run.

```
$ utility >file
```

The first thing that happens is that the shell notices the redirection, creates `file` (or truncates it if it already exists), *then* it executes `utility` with its standard output stream going into `file`.

The utility is not generally aware of or concerned with where its standard output is going (some, like `ls`, do check to see whether it's a TTY or not and changes their behaviour accordingly), so it doesn't matter whether it's writing to a regular file, pipe, device file or socket. It's certainly not concerned with *creating* this file. It is therefore the job of the shell to make sure that the plumbing is in place before the process is started, which includes creating or truncating the file named `file` in the example above.

For answers dealing with your issue regarding deleting all but the newest files, see the question "[remove oldest files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35792/remove-oldest-files)"

Answer (score 2):

While Kusalananda has answered your question about why `somefile.txt` appears in the output of `ls`, I'll try and address the question about how to delete all but the two most recently *created* files as the linked question deals with most recently *modified* files instead.

First, you don't have to write the output in a file. Commands can interact with each other directly, that's what pipes are for.

Here, you could do:

```
ls -tU | tail -n +3 | xargs echo rm -f -- # echo for dry-run
```

But that's flawed in the general case as `tail` works on lines and `xargs` works on (possibly quoted) words, and file names are not guaranteed to be either of those. They're not even guaranteed to be valid text. It would only work properly if none of the file names contain blanks, newlines, quotes, backslashes or byte sequences not forming valid characters.

If the system is FreeBSD (as your usage of `-U` suggests), you could use the `json` output format that is reliably parsable like:

```
ls --libxo=json -Ut |
  perl -MJSON::PP -l0 -0777 -ne '
    @files = map {$_->{name}} @{
      decode_json($_)->{"file-information"}->{directory}->[0]->{entry}
    };
    print for @files[2..$#files]' | xargs -0 echo rm -f --
```