# How to use the output of ls to open the last modified file?

Tags: ls, xargs

Would there be a way to use the output of `ls -ltr` with `xargs`?

Assume that the result of ls is one file as below.

```
ls -ltr | tail -1 | xargs -I{} open {}
```

For comparison, I use the following command to use find to move files:

```
find ~/Downloads/ -iname '*hello*' -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} mv {} ./
```

Can we somehow use NUL character?

---

**[Solved]**
As mentioned in the @illkachu's comments, the following works but is not suggested.

`somecmd "$(ls -tr | tail -1)"`

What Stéphane suggests seem be alternatives.

Comment: Using the output of `ls` is [number 
1 in BashPitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29). If you can tell what you want to do, we might be able to point to a better solution

Comment: Also: [BashFAQ 099: How can I get the newest (or oldest) file from a directory?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/099)

Comment: Maybe this Q if you want to process one or more of the newest files? [remove oldest files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/35792/170373). At least take a peek at the zsh solutions.

Comment: It is generally a [really bad idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) to parse the output of `ls`.  You should probably look into either using `find` or simple shell globbing to get your list of files to process.  Extensive further reading on the subject can be found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls).

Comment: @ilkkachu All references suggested seems to be informative and helpful. Nevertheless I still want a hacky one-liner, assuming that its an unstable solution..

Comment: @villybyun, for one file: `somecmd "$(ls -tr | tail -1)"` -- That will burn in a number of edge cases, most of which involve dashes, control characters or newlines in file names. I already feel like I've done something horrible, just writing that.

Comment: The resource from @DopeGhoti says, "don't know of any implementation of ls that allows you to terminate filenames with NUL characters instead of newlines". So, there would not be a way to use NUL then.

Comment: @ilkkachu `somecmd "$(ls -tr | tail -1)"` works. I understand that it is hacky and burns in edge cases, but still it is useful for my personal use. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you wouldn't as the output of `ls` is not post-processable reliably.

For instance:

```
open -- "$(ls -t | head -n 1)"
```

doesn't work if the name of newest file contains newline characters.

Ideally, you'd want:

```
ls -zt | head -zn1 | xargs -r0 open --
```

But unfortunately, I don't know of any `ls` implementation that supports a `-z`/`-0` option, and [the maintainers of GNU `ls` at least declined several times to add it](/q/112125).

Now, there are other ways with some implementations.

With the GNU and ast-open implementations of `ls`, in the C locale, the output with the `--quoting-style=shell-always` option is post-processable by `zsh`, `ksh93` or `bash`:

```
export LC_ALL=C
eval "files=($(ls --quoting-style=shell-always -t))"

open -- "${files[0]}" # $files[1] with zsh
```

Though in zsh, you'd just do

```
open ./*(om[1])
```

or:

```
open ./Ctrl+Xm
```

as `zsh` has built-in support to sort files by modification time (and many other criteria that go far beyond `ls` capabilities).

FreeBSD `ls` has a `--libxo` option to generate json or xml output, so you could do:

```
ls --libxo=json -t | perl -MJSON::PP -0777 -l0 -ne '
  print decode_json($_)
    ->{"file-information"}
    ->{directory}->[0]
    ->{entry}->[0]
    ->{name}' | xargs -r0 open --
```

But then it would be simpler to do the whole thing in `perl`.

Comment: I don't see the issue with using tr to replace tabs for nulls `ls -A | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -L 1 -0 echo`

Comment: @RayFoss, you're missing the point. That still doesn't work for file names that contain newline characters.

Comment: That zsh bit `open ./*(om[1])` is something special… to the .zshrc file with you!

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, it does when I add it as an alias. I was simply saying i'd never seen it, and that it was a gem. I've already added it and functions beautifully.

Comment: @visyoual. Ah OK, I'm with out now. I thought you said something along the lines of *the feature is specific to my .zshrc*.

Answer (score 1):

As you already have been told: In general this is not the approach you want to chose. However, as a start:

```
ls -ltr | awk '/^-/ { print $9; }' | xargs
```