# How to check if more than an instance of file exists and remove it

Tags: linux, bash

I have written a very simple script to make backup of my files and databases daily. This is my script:

```
mongodump --db DB
name=$( date +%F_%H_%M_%S )
tar zvcf /backup/$name-DB-db.tar.gz dump/
rm -rf dump
name=$( date +%F_%H_%M_%S )
tar zvcf /backup/$name-FILES-files.tar.gz /home/NAME/
```

It makes two `tar.gz` files each day, and after a week there will be 14 tar.gz files.

What I want is, suppose the below output of `ls -lh`:

```
2021-06-19_16_02_00-FILES-db.tar.gz
2021-06-19_17_02_00-FILES-db.tar.gz
2021-06-19_16_02_00-FILES-files.tar.gz
2021-06-19_17_02_00-FILES-files.tar.gz
2021-06-19_16_02_05-DB-db.tar.gz
2021-06-19_17_02_05-DB-db.tar.gz
2021-06-19_16_02_08-DB-files.tar.gz
2021-06-19_17_02_08-DB-files.tar.gz
```

What I want is:

```
Check if more than file {*FILES-db.tar.gz} exists, then remove the old ones and keep the last one. Else, skip.
Check if more than file {*DB-db.tar.gz} exists, then remove the old ones and keep the last one. Else, skip.
```

And the result of `ls -lh` after that should be something like this:

```
2021-06-19_17_02_00-FILES-db.tar.gz
2021-06-19_17_02_00-FILES-files.tar.gz
2021-06-19_17_02_05-DB-db.tar.gz
2021-06-19_17_02_08-DB-files.tar.gz
```

What function or commands should I use in my bash script?

I think it's better to use this function at the end of my bash script after making backup is done, but if there are better approaches and solutions, I'm eager to hear.

**Update 1**

`/etc/logrotate.d/NAME-files`:

```
/backup/*NAME-files.tar.gz {
        daily
        missingok
        rotate 1
        notifempty
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [logrotate](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate).

Comment: ... you could also consider switching to `zsh` where you can use glob qualifiers to select a range of files by modification time - see for example [remove oldest files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/160228/65304)

Comment: @dirkt thanks for logrotate recommendation. I tried to copy `nginx` logrorate file and one of my files is as I have edited the question. I ran the script again but it did not remove anything. I ran also `logrorate /etc/logrotate.d/NAME-files` but nothing was removed:(

Comment: @steeldriver thanks but I think using `logrotate` is a better idea since `zsh` is not installed and I should install (I know it's very simple but I'll consider this way as plan B)